# Iterate hbase resultscanner

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have issue with Hbase Result Scanner

This is my scenario

1. i have a list of Resultscanner(ListofScanner)
2. from this Resultscanner list i want extract all results as list of
   result(ListofResult)
3. and from result list i want iterate all cell values add to custom
   class list (Listclass)

So i coded like this

```
for(ResultScanner resca:ListofScanner)
{
for(Result Res:resca)
    {

    ListofResult.add(Res);


    }
}


for(Result rs:ListofResult)
{

   Listclass.add(Conver(rs));//Conver is function that converts results and return as a my class object

}
```

Here is the O/p

suppose i  expect this result form Listclass if a print a all values

```
gattner
lisa
Miely
luzz
```

But actual list i got

```
luzz
luzz
luzz
luzz
```

The last element of Listclass is got updated to all  values

I checked for each Result output after conversion ( Conver(rs) ) it returns as expected.
But only issue adding Listofclass.

I running with maven .so i couldn't debug this with Breakpointer .so Where did i miss?

Comment: Please add exact code you are using. The code you places is pseudo once , and hard to interpret which line is causing the issue

Comment: Place a debugger point and debug it line by line to see where the values are getting over written by the value  "luzz" . With this partial code we cannot intepret whats going on in there. If you are not using debugger, please use the following link to integrate the debugger http://www.practicalweb.co.uk/blog/2014/11/19/debugging-with-maven-and-eclipse/